# Better to check for null and avoid Null Ref Exception or simply catch Null Ref Exception

Tags: c#, exception, reference, null

I believe I know the answer to this, but I want to hear what the community has to say in order to make an exhaustive argument. Also, I believe there is a subtle different between this questions and the 1 other I see that is closely related:

**Fundamental Question**:  Is it better to check an object or member for null before accessing it and handle the result -OR- simply allow a NullReference Exception to be thrown and catch it?

Is there a security risk in allowing a Null Reference exception to be generated?

Is there any compelling reason to go with one style over the other?

Is there EVER a case where we would knowingly choose NOT to check for null and simply go with allow a Null Ref exception to be generated? (What if object was a db param set?)

Here's some example code to illustrate. Which is better / safer, MethodA() or MethodB()?

```
public string MethodA()
{
    ...
    try
    {
        ...
        ret = MyObject.Value?.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.HandleException(); }
    return ret;  // Caller has no discretion in handling empty string
}

public string MethodB()
{
    ...
    try
    {
        ...
        ret = MyObject.Value?.ToString();
        if (ret == null) ret = String.Empty;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.HandleException(); }
    return ret;  // Allow caller to manage case of empty string.
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It's c#. Sorry for not specifying.